# Error Configuring Email for SMTP

Tags: emails

I have tried to configure email as an SMTP client for a Google Mail server. When I click test I get a generic "There was an error testing your email settings", but no further info in Craft log files. The error displays almost instantly, so it does not seem like a connection issue, e.g. password / username error.

Craft is latest version and site is hosted with Arcustech.

Comment: Can you post your config (obfuscating your credentials of course)?

Comment: There should be an error getting logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` as well.

Comment: As I said in the post, no errors show up in the logs

Comment: Config settings: protocol:smtp    hostname:smtp.google.com   port:465  use SMTP authentication  Username:my email address Password:my password SMTP Secure Transport Type: SSL   Note that these settings are recommended by Google and the exact same settings work fine in my desktop email client

Answer (score 2):

Google considers SMTP to be an "insecure" protocol when connecting to their servers.  You have to explicitly go into your account settings as described [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) and enable access for these "insecure" requests.